# What does the phrase "contrasted coordinate elements" mean?

Tags: punctuation

> 7. Use a comma near the end of a sentence to separate contrasted coordinate elements or to indicate a distinct pause or shift.

What does "contrasted coordinate elements" mean?

Source: [owl.purdue.edu](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html)

Comment: The dresses came in blue, pink, and green. The dress came in pink, and green.

Comment: As in the first example given: _He was merely ignorant, not stupid_, where _ignorant_ and _stupid_  are contrasted.